# Combine DataFrame rows into a new column

Tags: julia

I am wondering if there is simple way to achieve this in Julia besides iterating over the rows in a for-loop.

I have a table with two columns that looks like this:

```
| Name | Interest |
|------|----------|
| AJ   | Football |
| CJ   | Running  |
| AJ   | Running  |
| CC   | Baseball |
| CC   | Football |
| KD   | Cricket  |
...
```

I'd like to create a table where each `Name` in first column is matched with a combined `Interest` column as follows:

```
| Name |        Interest      |
|------|----------------------|
| AJ   | Football, Running    |
| CJ   | Running              |
| CC   | Baseball, Football   |
| KD   | Cricket              |
...
```

How do I achieve this?

**UPDATE:** OK, so after trying a few things including `print_joint` and `grpby`, I realized that the easiest way to do this would be `by()` function. I'm 99% there.

```
by(myTable, :Name, df->DataFrame(Interest = string(df[:Interest])))
```

This gives me my `:Interest` column as `"UTF8String[\"Running\"]"`, and I can't figure out which method I should use instead of `string()` (or where to typecast) to get the desired ASCIIString output.

Comment: Try `join(df[:Interest], ", ")` instead of `string(…)`.

Comment: @MattB. Haah! It was that simple! Thanks. Works like a well-programmed charm! Thank you sir.

Comment: @MattB. You should post your comment as an answer :)

Comment: how about sample data to make this question fit in the stackoverflow standard of good questions?